# opengl vbo advice

Tags: opengl, vbo

I have a model designed in Blender that i am going to render, in my game engine built using opengl, after exporting it to collada. The model in blender is divided into groups. These groups contains vertices normals and textures with there own index. is it a good thing to do if i rendered each group as a separate vbo or should i render the whole model as a single vbo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules of thumb are:

- always do as few OpenGL state changes as possible;
- always talk to OpenGL as little as possible.

The main reason being that talking to the GPU is costly. The GPU is much happier if you give it something it'll take a long time to do and then don't bother it again while it's working. So it's likely that a single VBO would be a better solution, unless it would lead to a substantial increase in the amount of storage you need to use and hence run against caching elsewhere.