# OpenGL structure of VAO/VBO for model with moving parts?

Tags: opengl, vbo

I came from this question:

[opengl vbo advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837774/opengl-vbo-advice)

I use OpenGL 3.3 and will not to use deprecated features. Im using Assimp to import my blender models. But im a bit confused as to how much i should split them up in terms of VAO's and VBO's.

First off a little side question. I use glDrawElements, do that mean i cannot interleave my vertex attributes or can the VAO figure out using the glVertexAttribPointer and the glDrawElements offset to see where my vertex position is?

Main question i guess, boils down to how do i structure my VAO/VBO's for a model with multiple moving parts, and multiple meshes pr. part.

Each node in assimp can contain multiple meshes where each mesh has texture, vertices, normals, material etc. The nodes in assimp contains the transformations. Say i have a ship with a cannon turret on it. I want to be able to roatate the turret. Do this mean i will make the ship node a seperate VAO with VBO's for each mesh containing its attributes(or multiple VBO's etc.).
I guess it goes like

```
draw(ship);    //call to draw ship VAO
pushMatrix(turretMatrix)  //updating uniform modelview matrix for the shader
draw(turret);  //call to draw turret VAO
```

I don't fully understand UBO(uniform buffer objects) yet, but it seems i can pass in multiple uniforms, will that help me contain a full model with moveable parts in a single VAO?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

first, off VAO only "remembers" the last vertex attribute bindings (and VBO binding for an index buffer (the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`), if there is one). So it does not remember offsets in `glDrawElements()`, you need to call that later when using the VAO. It laso does not prevent you from using interleaved vertex arrays. Let me try to explain:

```
int vbo[3];
glGenBuffers(3, vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data0, size0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data1, size1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data2, size2);
// create some buffers and fill them with data

int vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
// create a VAO

{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]); // not saved in VAO
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * sizeof(float), NULL); // this is VAO saved state
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // this is VAO saved state
    // sets up one vertex attrib array from vbo[0] (say positions)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]); // not saved in VAO
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float), NULL); // this is VAO saved state
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float), (const void*)(2 * sizeof(float))); // this is VAO saved state
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // this is VAO saved state
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // this is VAO saved state
    // sets up two more VAAs from vbo[1] (say normals interleaved with texcoords)

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]); // this is VAO saved state
    // uses the third buffer as the source for indices
}
// set up state that VAO "remembers"

glBindVertexArray(0); // bind different vaos, etc ...
```

Later ...

```
glBindVertexArray(vao); // bind our VAO (so we have VAAs 0, 1 and 2 as well as index buffer)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 57, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 23, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const void*)(57 * sizeof(unsigned int)));
// draws two parts of the mesh as triangle strips
```

So you see ... you can draw interleaved vertex arrays using `glDrawElements` using a single VAO and one or more VBOs.

To answer the second part of your question, you either can have different VAOs and VBOs for different parts of the mesh (so drawing separate parts is easy), or you can fuse all into one VAO VBO pair (so you need not call `glBind*()` often) and use multiple `glDraw*()` calls to draw individual parts of the mesh (as seen in the code above - imagine the first `glDrawElements()` draws the ship and the second draws the turret, you just update some matrix uniform between the calls).

Because shaders can contain multiple modelview matrices in uniforms, you can also encode mesh id as another vertex attribute, and let the vertex shader choose which matrix to use to transform the vertex, based on this attribute. This idea can also be extended to using multiple matrices per a single vertex, with some weights assigned for each matrix. This is commonly used when animating organic objects such as player character (look up "skinning").

As uniform buffer objects go, the only advantage is that you can pack a lot of data into them and that they can be easily shared between shaders (just bind the UBO to any shader that is able to use it). There is no real advantage in using them for you, except if you would be to have objects with 1OOOs of matrices.

Also, i wrote the source codes above from memory. Let me know if there are some errors / problems ...

Comment: Cool i think i get it with the interleaving, have to try it out. But i think you made a mistake so just to be sure, in defning the first glVertexAttribPointer for the vertex positions, as i understood it the vertex positions are tightly packed in vbo[0] yet you gave it a stride? Shouldn't the stride be zero for the positions since they are not interleaved.

Comment: I like the idea about the mesh ID in the shader and pass it as a attribute but how would i go about parsing in many matrixes into the shader(like a uniform array)? Is this where i can use UBO's to pass in say maybe 10 different transformation matrixes for 10 different turrets and use a index parsed as a attribute to look up the correct matrix inside the shader?
This would also enable me to use the glMultiDrawElements/Arrays functions drawing a whole ship with multiple parts all at one go?

Comment: Hi, good observation with the stride. But it's not an error. Either i could leave stride 0 and OpenGL would know (from the second and third argument) that i have stream of 3D GL_FLOATS (and therefore size is 3 * sizeof(float)), or i can calculate the stride for it. There's nothing wrong with that. To further clarify - stride is distance between addresses of two consecutive vertices, it is NOT the space between them (therefore 0 doesn't mean there are no unused bytes between the vertices, it means that OpenGL should calculate the real stride from number of dimensions and data type used).

Comment: And as for the other comment I would say that passing 10 matrices can be safely done using uniform array. Using uniform buffer object does pretty much the same, the only difference is you need to alloc buffer object, load it with the matrices, and bind it to the shader (to me, that sounds like more work than calling glUniformMatrix4fv()). And yes, that means rendering the whole model using glMultiDraw*(). If you'd like, i could write a simple demo for you ... just let me know.

Comment: It's ok it looks simple enough parsing in an array. Only problem i could see is i use GLM math library, not sure how that is going to work with value_ptr() etc. but ill figure it out. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @theswine can you elaborate on how to bind a UBO of say 100 transform matrices to a vertex shader and how you would then access them? I understand putting a matrix index into my vertex+data UBO so I have access to it in the shader, and I understand how to use a `uniform mat4 myTransforms[10];` and accessing a particular matrix using that index, but there is a limit on uniform storage space on most devices, so this couldn't scale for 100's of transforms. Any pointers to a vertex shader that pulls from a separate matrix UBO based on the current index? thanks for the rest of this answer, also.

Comment: @natbro what device are you using? i have GeForce GTX 260 and it has max uniform buffer bindings: 36 and max uniform block size: 64.00 kB. that means i have 64 kB in each uniform block and that i have 36 uniform buffer bindings. that means i could store 35 * 64 (i believe the 36 also include the default block) = 2.2 MB of uniform data. and anyway, a single matrix has 4x4xsizeof(float) = 64 Bytes, that means you could fit 1024 of them to an uniform block. does your device have lower limit? or is there a particular error you are struggling with?

Comment: @theswine: iphone/ipad, so powervr sgx which claims [per apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH106-SW1) room in uniform space for "128 uniform vectors (4x4xfloat) in a vertex shader and up to 64 uniform vectors in a fragment shader", which i translate to room for 32 transforms. i could bind and swap uniform buffers, but keep thinking there must be a way to keep a bigger transform array on-GPU and be indexing it from the vertex shader.

Comment: @natbro you're in bad luck. your hw does only allow static uniforms (no EXT_bindable_uniform nor uniform_buffer_object). so you're stuck with good old uniforms, and not many of them. you also can't use textures as a lookup because such hardware doesn't support vertex texture fetch (although i might be mistaken here, look up what's the value of GL_MAX_VERTEX_IMAGE_UNITS). i guess you need to break your model down to simpler parts (so that it fits with the limited number of transforms). or use some kind of procedural transforms. it might be useful what is is you are trying to do.

Comment: @theswine Maybe I'm wrong but I thought: GL_ARRAY_BUFFER state is not saved by VAOs (just indirectly captured through glVertexAttribPointer). Could you clarify this in your answer please.

Comment: @tauran There's a difference between GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding ("which vertex buffer is active - a number (name) of VBO in OpenGL") and between vertex attribute pointers ("binding of address inside vertex buffer to a certain vertex attribute - a pointer to data in GPU"). GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding is not a part of VAO saved state (VAO doesn't remember which vertex buffers were bound). VAO only remembers the vertex array pointers, which themselves point to the data in the buffers, without the need to remember the buffer number itself. The GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding is a different story, though.

Comment: Yes, but your sample code looks like this:
`glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]); // this is VAO saved state`

Answer (score 0):

@theswine

Not binding this during VAO initialization causes my program to crash, but binding it after binding the VAO causes it to run correctly. Are you sure this isn't saved in the VAO?

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]); // not saved in VAO
```

(BTW: sorry for bringing up an old topic, I just thought this could be useful to others, this post sure was! (which reminds me, thank you!!))

Comment: Hi. I just saw this by accident, as users don't get notified when you post an answer, starting with `@ login` (only the OP is notified of that). You should have left a comment in my answer, I would be notified of that. I suggest that you start a new question and post some minimal code that reproduces your crash. Would that be possible? Then you can leave me a `@ login` comment below this comment and I'll look into your problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was unable to comment on your post due to my lack of reputation. But ill try to throw something together for you to check out (maybe its just my hardware?)

Comment: It is usually just a swapped index or tangled binding. Happens to the best. Sometimes, the element array (index) buffer makes problems, especially on Intel graphics cards.